# Numpy cluster from connected graph

Tags: python, graph, numpy

What is the best way to cluster connected graph ?

ex1 :

```
[[ 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [ 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [ 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [ 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [ 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [ 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

result :

```
==> [[0,1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

ex2

```
[[ 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [ 1 1 0 1 0 0]
 [ 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [ 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [ 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [ 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

result :

```
==> [[0,1,3],[2,4,5]]
```

ex3

```
[[ 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [ 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [ 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [ 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [ 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [ 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

result :

```
==> [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]]
```

thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html

but can you explain why the result of ex2 is [[0,1,3],[2,4,5]]?

Comment: with column, 0,1,3 are connected and 2,4,5 also

Answer (score 2):

In some of the examples, say `ex2`, you've given a digraph, or a directed graph such that `A != A.T`. In this case a more reasonable definition can be found by considering [*strongly connected components*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). In this case the splitting is `[0,1,3],[4,5],[2]`. [`networkx`](http://networkx.github.com/) can help you find these:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

A = np.array([[0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [1,1,0,1,0,0],
              [0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [1,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,1],
              [0,0,0,0,1,1]])

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph()) 
for subg in nx.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs(G):
    print subg.nodes()
```