# Clustering some graph form matrix

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, networkx

A few questions on stackoverflow mention similar problem, but...

I have a square matrix, for example like this:

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D 
A |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0 
B |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0 
C |  0  |  1  |  1  |  0 
D |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1
```

The square matrix can be of any size (can be 1000x1000 or larger). I want to get clusters (I don't know how many...). For the above example I should get two clusters:

1. A, B, C (because A-B and B-C)
2. D

Comment: cluster-computing tag seems unrelated

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386414

Comment: Seems like maybe cluster is the wrong word here. It sounds like you are looking for paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy cluster from connected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386414/numpy-cluster-from-connected-graph)

Comment: please explicitly define "cluster" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

1. The example you gave is a classic **clique detection**, well studied in graph theory with several algorithms. It gets more interesting when you allow some edges to be missing. This will lead to **modularity** etc.
2. What you have is an unweighted adjacency matrix. There are clustering algorithms that work on this - affinity propagation needs an affinity, and hierarchical agglomerative clustering *can* be implemented with similarities (beware, most implementations use distances)
3. In your case, you can trivially use 1-X as distance matrix for many many clustering algorithm except k-means and GMM and a few other exceptions that require a coordinate matrix.